# Null editexts in databinding activity

Tags: android, android-databinding

How to set data in editexts with databinding from Viewmodel?
I'm passing parameters from the RecyclerView Item to the ViewModel in OnItemClick and in logs everything looks fine, but the Edittexts are still empty. when I tried to set the String created in ViewModel and was the same. EditTexts are still empty. I no have idea where is error.

ViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel extends AndroidViewModel implements RecyclerViewAdapter.OnItemClickListener {

private TaskRepository taskRepository;
private LiveData<List<Task>> allTasks;
public ObservableField<String> description = new ObservableField<>();
public ObservableField<String> date = new ObservableField<>();
public ObservableField<String> time = new ObservableField<>();
String TAG;


public MainViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
    taskRepository = new TaskRepository(application);
    allTasks = taskRepository.getAllTasks();
}

public LiveData<List<Task>> getAllTasks() {
    return allTasks;
}

public void deleteTask(Task task) {
    taskRepository.delete(task);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(View view, Task item) {
    Log.d(TAG, "MVM " + view + " / " + item.getDescription() + " / " + item.getDate() + " / " + item.getTime());
    description.set(item.getDescription());
    date.set(item.getDate());
    time.set(item.getTime());
}
```

XML file:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<data>

    <variable
        name="editTaskViewModel"
        type="com.example.daniellachacz.taskmvvm.viewmodel.MainViewModel">
    </variable>

    <variable
        name="editTaskInterface"
        type="com.example.daniellachacz.taskmvvm.view.OnEditTaskClickInterface">
    </variable>

</data>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFF">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:text="Edit task"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="25sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_description_text"
                android:layout_width="320dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/title"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/title"
                android:backgroundTint="#FFF"
                android:text="@={editTaskViewModel.description}"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textColorHint="#949393"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/edit_date_text"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/edit_time_text"
            android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="Select date"
            android:onClick="@{()-> editTaskInterface.onEditDateClick()}"
            android:text="@={editTaskViewModel.date}"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/line"
            android:layout_width="320dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/date_text"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/edit_time_text"
            android:layout_width="132dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="231dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="Select time"
            android:onClick="@{()-> editTaskInterface.onEditTimeClick()}"
            android:text="@={editTaskViewModel.time}"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/and"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="230dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="and"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/edit_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="115dp"
            android:onClick="@{()-> editTaskInterface.onEditClick()}"
            android:text="Edit" />

    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

EditTaskActivity:

```
public class EditTaskActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RecyclerViewAdapter.OnItemClickListener {

private String TAG;
public EditTaskActivityBinding editTaskActivityBinding;
private MainViewModel mainViewModel;
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateSetListener;
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timeSetListener;


@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    editTaskActivityBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.edit_task_activity);
    mainViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel.class);
    editTaskActivityBinding.setEditTaskViewModel(mainViewModel);

    dateSetListener = (view, year, month, dayOfMonth) -> {
        month = month + 1;
        Log.d(TAG, "onDataSet: dd/mm/yyyy: " + year + "/" + month + "/" + dayOfMonth);
        String date = dayOfMonth + "/" + month + "/" + year;
        editTaskActivityBinding.editDateText.setText(date);
    };

    timeSetListener = (view, hourOfDay, minute) -> {
        Log.d(TAG, "onTimeSet: hh/mm: " + hourOfDay + "/" + minute);
        String time = hourOfDay + ":" + minute;
        editTaskActivityBinding.editTimeText.setText(time);
    };

    editTaskActivityBinding.setEditTaskInterface(new OnEditTaskClickInterface() {
        @Override
        public void onEditClick() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onEditDateClick() {
            showDatePicker();
        }

        @Override
        public void onEditTimeClick() {
            showTimePicker();
        }
    });
}

public void showDatePicker() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_MinWidth, dateSetListener,
            year, month, day);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dialog.show();
}

public void showTimePicker() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hourOfDay = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    TimePickerDialog dialog = new TimePickerDialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_MinWidth, timeSetListener,
            hourOfDay, minute, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(this));
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: stacktrace please

Comment: have you debugged your code ?. And take a look at your logs maybe you can find the problem.

Comment: Could you add activity/fragment where `MainViewModel` is used?

Comment: @Umair
Yes. I have the parameters in ViewModel. I also set normal String created in method and the Textviews are empty.

Comment: @ConstOrVar
I just pasted code in my main comment.

Comment: @Basi
You want all stactrace from logcat?

Comment: Ok, I know the problem. There is no initialised onItemClick method in onCreate in Activity. So I have question. How to correctly with MVVM Databinding open this method in Activity? Just initiate in onCreate?